# Field of Quotients of an integral domain may also be a field of quotients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm trying to show by an example that a field $F$ of quotients of a proper subdomain $A$ of an integral domain $D$ may also be a field of quotients of $D$. I have no idea where to begin. Help?

Comment: Instead of starting with $D$, start somewhere between $D$ and $F$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $B$ be a domain which is not a field, and let $K$ be its field of quotients.

To get your example, pick $D=K$, so that $F=K$, and $A=B$.

Comment: What about D = $\mathbb{Z}$ F=$\mathbb{Q}$ and A=$2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In this context one usually one considers subrings which contain the same $1$. apart from that: what about that?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** $\ $ Any ring between a domain and its fraction field necessarily has the same fraction field. For some nontrivial examples consider $\rm\:\mathbb Z\subset$ [dyadic $\mathbb Q$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) $\rm = \{\: m/2^n\ :\ m\in \mathbb Z,\ n\in \mathbb N\:\}\ $ and consider $\rm\:\mathbb Z\subset$  $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ $\rm = \{\: m/n\ :\ m\in \mathbb Z,\ odd\ n\in \mathbb Z\:\}\:.$